# bind input to object array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a JSON input like this:

```
$scope.managers = 
[
    {
        managerName : "Sam",
        employeesList: [
        { employeeName: 'Joe', employeeCategory: 'Developer' },
        { employeeName: 'Bob', employeeCategory: 'Developer' }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to bind all the `employeeNames` for that manager to one comma separated input something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="manager in managers">
    <input type="text" ng-model="manager.employeesList.employeeName" ng-list />
</div>
```

So that I can just enter

> John, Bob

in the input field.

What is the best way to do this?

(I cannot change the structure of the JSON object)

Comment: Back to the actual question; I suspect the only way to do what you want is going to be by writing some the parsing code of the user's input in order to save it in the proper places.

Comment: @JeffryHouser any suggestions on the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a button that on `ng-click="storeNames(nameInput, manager)`.

`.split()` takes a string and separates it into elements of an array every time it sees a selector (which in this case is ', ')

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
    $scope.nameInput = '';
    $scope.managers = [
            {
            managerName: 'Billy Joe',
            employeesList: [
                { employeeName: 'Joe', employeeCategory: 'Developer' },
                { employeeName: 'Bob', employeeCategory: 'Developer' }
                ]
            }
        ];

    $scope.storeNames = function(names, manager) {
        if(names.length > 0) {
            names.split(", ");
            for(var x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
                manager.employeesList.employeeName[x] = names[x];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: correct. i did this already. that is not the issue. i will edit the question to clarify

Comment: what I am trying to do is input all the employee names for that manager in one input field, i.e. Joe, Bob

Comment: I'm putting together a fiddle for you real quick.

Comment: actually i ended up just editing my answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I've edited it again to fix a couple typos. I'm also pretty new to angular but have been using it professionally for about 4 months now. So I'd also learn a lot from helping you out if you need any more.

Comment: For example if I were doing this for work I would probably turn it into a directive...

Comment: Thanks a lot- were getting closer. I think directive is the way to go as I cant really add a new button. Also fyi ng-list will ideally give you an array, so there shouldnt really be a need to split